# How to prevent app falling in sleeping status on Mac?

Tags: mac, macos

As the title asked, the office Mac Pro can keep running without falling in sleeping, however, the program, like TeamView, always falls in sleeping so I cannot remotely communicate with my office computer. 
I can remote log in my office computer using xshell and reboot it, and then remote log in TeamView. Is there any other way to change the sleeping status using commands or prevent the software falling in sleep?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

MacPro 5
Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Have you tried an app like Caffeinated or Caffeine which keeps your mac awake?  Maybe it works for apps too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My MacPro does not fall in sleep. I need to keep my software awake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the App Nap feature on any app by finding it in Applications, Get Info, then uncheck App Nap.

[image]

The App Nap checkbox doesn't appear for all apps - & I can't figure out what determines that.

Otherwise, you can disable it globally from Terminal using the command
`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES`